# Cambiar posición de divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hay alguna forma de cambiar la posición entre divs por ejemplo tengo 3 divs

```html
<div class="form-row" id="div1">
  <label>Datos div 1</label>
</div>
<div class="form-row" id="div2">
  <label>Datos div 2</label>
</div>
<div class="form-row" id="div3">
  <label>Datos div 3</label>
</div>
```

Y cambiarlo el orden de la siguiente manera

```html
<div class="form-row" id="div1">
  <label>Datos div 2</label>
</div>
<div class="form-row" id="div2">
  <label>Datos div 1</label>
</div>
<div class="form-row" id="div3">
  <label>Datos div 3</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar cajas flexibles. Envolviendo a tus `<div>` en un contenedor al que le des `display: flex` puedes usar `order` para colocar a sus hijos como necesites.

```css
.contenedor {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#div1 {
  order: 2;
}

#div2 {
  order: 1;
}

#div3 {
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="form-row" id="div1">
    <label>Datos div 1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row" id="div2">
    <label>Datos div 2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row" id="div3">
    <label>Datos div 3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```